# $A+B$ Borel set if $A$ is countable, open.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

If $A,B \subset \Bbb{R}$ , we define 
 $$ A+B = \{a+b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}. $$

Suppose $B$ is a Borel set, then we need to

> prove that $A+B$ is a Borel set if
>
> - $A$ is countable.
> - $A$ is open.

Borel sets are the sets that can be constructed starting from the open and closed sets by repeatedly taking countable unions and intersections.

But how to apply the countable intersection/ union to this problem? Here we are taking the sum of two sets.

Since any homomorphism preserves the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets, I thought of considering the translation map $f:B \rightarrow A+B$ where $f(b) = a+b$. Will this do or I have to make more precise arguments?

I cannot apply the fact that difference of two Borel sets is a Borel set since I do not know whether $A$ is a Borel set or not.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. You do know whether $A$ is Borel or not. Actually, this is useful to solve the problem, so start by showing this: In both cases, $A$ is Borel.

Comment: Also, I do not understand what your function $f$ is. Is $a$ fixed? Does it vary? You thought of that function, which is a translation. Ok. What about it? How does that help? You will certainly need more precise arguments than a vague idea.

Comment: I see I have to be precise, let me think more!

Comment: If $A$ is open, then $A+B$ is open because $A+B=\{A+b\mid b\in B\}$ is a union of open sets. In this case, $B$ can be arbitrary, not necessarily Borel.

Answer (score 4):

The case when $A$ is open is hard because people miss how easy it is.

Let $a+b \in A+B$ be arbitrary. Since $A$ is open, there exist some $\epsilon>0$ such that $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon) \subset A$.

Then
$$(a+b-\epsilon, a+b+\epsilon) \subset A+B$$
and hence $A+B$ is **open** .

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is countable, then $A+B=\bigcup\{a+B:a\in A\}$ is a countable union of Borel sets.

Comment: Yes nice!! but how to deal with open?

Comment: @BAYMAX what can you say about $A+b$ for $b$ fixed?